# How can I fix duplicate requests?

Tags: reactjs

I'm starting to learn React, and I'm having trouble executing a request, or rather, two requests are made instead of one. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDocumentTitle } from "../use/useDocumentTitle";
import axios from "axios";

function NewsPage() {
  const parms = useParams();
  const [news, setNews] = useState([]);
  const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (fetching) {
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:3000/tz.php", {
          params: {
            id: parms.id,
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.data != null) {
            setNews(response.data);
            console.log(response.data);
          }
        })
        .finally(() => {
      setFetching(false);
});
    }
    console.log("fetching " + fetching);
  }, []);
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***useEffect Run Twice in React v18.0.***

If you need to run once, you can disable strict mode in ***index.js*** file which is not recommended.

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode> // remove strict mode from here, not recommended
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

More on details [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/react-v18-0-useeffect-bug-why-do-effects-run-twice-39babecede93)

In production build, it'll be solved and useEffect hook will be called only once.

Answer (score 0):

In your `finally` block, add the following:

```js
setFetching(false);
```

As a 1liner, it would look like:

```js
.finally(() => setFetching(false));
```

This should stop re-fetching.

*Is that why you created that state variable or you're using it anywhere else?*

Comment: oops, I accidentally deleted it when I added the code. Doesn't work with him either. I don't use this variable anywhere else. Only to stop duplicating requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an effect that calls an API in a hook or component that is on the screen multiple times, on first load - even on a production build - duplicate API calls can be an issue.  One solution I've found is to keep track of the ongoing API call outside of the scope of the component.  Here's an example using of a hook that sits on top of redux that de-dups the calls to load projects.

```
let projectsPromise: Promise<any> | null = null;

export default function useProjects() {
  const projects = useSelector(selectAllProjects); // using redux as cache

  const loadProjects = async () => {
    if (!projectsPromise) {
      projectsPromise = dispatch(getAllProjects()); // api call to retrieve projects
      await projectsPromise;
      projectsPromise = null;
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (projects === undefined) {
      loadProjects();
    }
  }, [Boolean(projects)]);

  return { projects };
}
```